What is Caja doing to suck up CPU cycles?
I have Caja windows open (quite a few) but I'm not doing anything with them, yet Caja is grabbing 100% of a CPU every few seconds.  It puts a noticable load on the system, and makes scrolling in a Caja window very erratic.  It also aggravates other problems in Caja (next question).
You can see from the System Monitor screenshot (viewing Active Processes) that only it and Caja are running and Caja is using 17% on an eight CPU system.  The Monitor trace shows the periodic loads, from Caja, about 13 times a minute, and sucking a CPU.


Does anyone know what is causing the loads in Caja?  And what I can do to alleviate its drag on the system (and itself)?
Release 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.18.10-76051810-generic x86_64
MATE 1.24.0
Caja 1.24.0

Your details show a System 76 (Pop OS) kernel, are you using Ubuntu?  also an outdated MATE version that is out of guaranteed support in Ubuntu
